# Javascript New Date() returns invalid date

Tags: javascript, date

I have an Array with date strings formatted: "24-Jul-2017".
and when i use `new Date("24-Jul-2017");`
it returns date with one day offset.
`2017-07-23T22:00:00.000Z`

Tried different formatting but could not get correct date.

Comment: can you get typeof("24-Jul-2017") your string before you run new Date("24-Jul-2017"). Mine is working fine, but I'm thinking that you may have a codepoint issue, or have you done anything to the Date.prototype object?

Comment: it is type of string

Comment: Are you displaying using `toISOString` by any chance?.. If you want to display in local time, using the local display options. like `toString`, `toLocaleString` etc.  If you display using a UTC format, you will get a UTC time.  makes sense?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the browser is in a time zone with a UTC offset of +2 at the start of July 24th 2017, it's behaving as documented.

The [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) is documented as behaving like [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), which then includes this documentation - along with multiple warnings **not to use the constructor accepting a string, or the `parse` method**:

> Given a date string of "March 7, 2014", parse() assumes a local time zone, but given an ISO format such as "2014-03-07" it will assume a time zone of UTC (ES5 and ECMAScript 2015). Therefore Date objects produced using those strings may represent different moments in time depending on the version of ECMAScript supported unless the system is set with a local time zone of UTC. This means that two date strings that appear equivalent may result in two different values depending on the format of the string that is being converted.

So it's providing you July 24th 2017 at midnight *in the local time zone*.

It sounds to me like you'd be better off using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) or something similar to give you clearer control over the parsing/formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second))
```

Try this format (UTC will be the timezone for your Date)